# Distance from origin to plane (shortest)

Tags: math, 3d

So I was reading over something on this page (http://gamedeveloperjourney.blogspot.com/2009/04/point-plane-collision-detection.html)

The author mentioned

```
 d = - D3DXVec3Dot(&vP1, &vNormal);
```

where vP1 is a point on the plane and vNormal is the normal to the plane. I'm curious as to how this gets you the distance from the world origin since the result will always be 0. In addition, just to be clear (since I'm still kind of hazy on the d part of a plane equation), is d in a plane equation the distance from a line through the world origin to the plane's origin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the generic case the distance between a point `p` and a plane can be computed by

```
<p - p0, normal>
```

where `<a, b>` is the dot product operation

```
<a, b> = ax*bx + ay*by + az*bz
```

and where `p0` is a point on the plane.

[image: plane-point distance]

When `n` is of unity length the dot product between a vector and it is the (signed) length of the projection of the vector on the normal

The formula you are reporting is just the special case when the point `p` is the origin. In this case

```
distance = <origin - p0, normal> = - <p0, normal>
```

This equality is formally wrong because the dot product is about vectors, not points... but still holds numerically. Writing down the explicit formula you get that

```
(0 - p0.x)*n.x + (0 - p0.y)*n.y + (0 - p0.z)*n.z
```

is the same as

```
- (p0.x*n.x + p0.y*n.y + p0.z*n.z)
```

Indeed a nice way to store a plane is to save the normal `n` and the value of `k = <p0, n>` where `p0` is any point on the plane (the value of `k` is independent on which point you choose of the plane).

Comment: The normal is a normal from the surface plane though. If the point is already a point on the plane then they will be at a 90 degree angle and thus, the answer will always be 0. I don't get how this is distance from the origin to a plane, especially if the plane were a random distance from the origin. 

Also, I do get what it means logically and geometrically in terms of finding out the relation of a point to a surface. The only one thing that has me caught up is this.

Answer (score 2):

The result is not always zero.  The result will only be zero if the plane goes through the origin.  (Here let's assume the plane doesn't go through the origin.)

Basically, you are given a line from the origin to some point on the plane.  (I.e. you have a vector from the origin to vP1).  The problem with this vector is that most likely it's slanted and going to some far away place on the plane rather than to the closest point on the plane.  So, if you simply took the length of vP1 you will get a distance that is too big.

What you need to do is get the projection of vP1 onto some vector that you know is perpendicular to the plane.  That of course is vNormal.  So take the dot product of vP1 and vNormal, and divide by the length of vNormal and you have the answer.  (If they are kind enough to give you a vNormal that already is magnitude one, then no need to divide.)

Answer (score 1):

You can work this out with Lagrange multipliers:

You know that the closest point on the plane must be of the form:

```
c = p + v
```

Where `c` is the closest point and `v` is a vector along the plane (which is thus orthogonal to `n`, the normal).  You are trying for find the `c` with the smallest norm (or norm squared).  So you are trying to minimized `dot(c,c)` subject to `v` being orthogonal to `n` (thus `dot(v,n) = 0`).

Thus, set up Lagrangian:

```
L = dot(c,c) + lambda * ( dot(v,n) )
L = dot(p+v,p+v) + lambda * ( dot(v,n) )
L = dot(p,p) + 2*dot(p,v) + dot(v,v) * lambda * ( dot(v,n) )
```

And take the derivative with respect to `v` (and set to 0) to get:

```
2 * p + 2 * v + lambda * n = 0
```

You can solve for lambda by in the equation above by dot producting both sides by `n` to get

```
2 * dot(p,n) + 2 * dot(v,n) + lambda * dot(n,n) = 0
2 * dot(p,n) + lambda = 0
lambda = - 2 * dot(p,n)
```

Note again that `dot(n,n) = 1` and `dot(v,n) = 0` (since `v` is in the plane and `n` is orthogonal to it).  Then subtitute `lambda` back in to get:

```
2 * p + 2 * v - 2 * dot(p,n) * n = 0
```

and solve for `v` to get:

```
v = dot(p,n) * n - p
```

Then plug this back into `c = p + v` to get:

```
c = dot(p,n) * n
```

The length of this vector is `|dot(p,n)|` and the sign tells you whether the point is in the direction of the normal vector from the origin, or the reverse direction from the origin.