# shortest distance from plane to origin using a plane equation

Tags: python, 3d, plane

suppose i have a plane equation ax+by+cz=d, how can I go about finding the shortest distance from the plane to the origin?

I am going in reverse of this post. In this post, they start out with a point P0 and the normal. In my case, I only have the plane equation
[Distance from origin to plane (shortest)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540531/distance-from-origin-to-plane-shortest)

Here is what I have so far.

```
        #calculate the distance from plane to origin
        dist=math.sqrt(new_a**2+new_b**2+new_c**2)

        x_dist=(a*d)/dist
        y_dist=(b*d)/dist
        z_dist=(c*d)/dist
```

Answer (score 1):

The normal of your plane is `[a,b,c]`. Multiply it by `d` and get the length of the result. This should give you what you need.